# How to add a margin between the chart area and the chart line?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using chart js and I have made a line chart. I have tried multiple ways and went through the whole documentation but I cannot find the way to do this.
I have tried using the gradient to bring some whitespace between the chart-area-background and line.
Do I need to make a plugin for this small requirement? I need a margin or whitespace between the line and the chart area background.

```
function App() {
  var options = {
    // layout: {
    //   padding: {
    //     left: 50,
    //     right: 0,
    //     // top: 100,
    //     bottom: 100
    //   }
    // },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            drawBorder: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            drawBorder: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  };
  const data = canvas => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 49, 0, 500);
    // gradient.addColorStop(0.6, "white");    
    gradient.addColorStop(0.21, "rgba(226,240,251,1)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.54, "rgba(244,249,253,1)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "rgba(251,253,254,1)");

    return {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          lineTension: 0.5,
          fill:true,
          backgroundColor: gradient,
          borderColor: "#347aeb",
          borderCapStyle: "butt",
          borderDash: [],
          borderWidth: 5,
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          borderJoinStyle: "round",
          pointBorderColor: "#347AEB",
          pointBackgroundColor: "white",
          pointBorderWidth: 5,
          pointHoverRadius: 5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 10,
          pointHitRadius: 10,

          // showLine: 0,
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
      ]
    };
  };

  return (

    
      <Line data={data} width={100} height={400} options={options}></Line>

  );
}
```

[image: I need to add a margin where I have pointed it out.]